# Eclipse - break during debug when a struct member achieves a certain value

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, debugging

I have seen similar questions on SO, but have not found the answer to my question. I will use the sample code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _test {
    int x;
    int y;
} test;

test t1;

int thread1 () {

    int i, j, k;
    i = 0; // i want to break here IF t1.x == 10

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

A thread other than the thread executing `thread1` could be changing `t1`.

I want the **Eclipse IDE** to break during debug execution at the assignment for `i`, as I have indicated in the comment.

I have tried putting up a **conditional breakpoint**. For the condition I have set:

```
t1.x == 10
```

However, it is *not* breaking, even though the value of 10 is achieved.

Firstly, is it possible, and secondly, is this the right way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: try declaring `t1` as `volatile test t1;`

Comment: what does this have to do with Eclipse?

Comment: People iceman asking if he can debug his program. How is that related to code?

Comment: I don't see any reason that eclipse doesn't stop the program there. did you tried to debug another simple program?